# SQL Server 2012 add value of rows with matching ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm doing an assignment on SQL Server 2012 where I have to

> 7) Create a stored procedure (call it `SQL7`) which will retrieve the
>   Charity ID and Charity Name and the total of all the contribution
>   amounts that each charity has in the contribution table."

`Charity ID` and `Charity Name` are in one table and the second table has `CharityID` and `Total` contributions.

I don't know how to add the total contributions that each charity has received and output it. The code I have so far is

```
create proc SQL7
as
   select distinct 
       dbo.CharityTbl.CharityID, CharityName,
   from 
       dbo.CharityTbl, dbo.ContributionsTbl
   where 
      dbo.CharityTbl.CharityID = dbo.ContributionsTbl.CharityID
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need grouping (assuming table1 holds charity information and table2 holds contribution information)

```
create procedure SQL7
as
  select a.charityid, a.charityname, sum(b.totalcontributions) as totals
  from CharityTbl a
  left join ContributionsTbl b on a.charityid = b.charityid
  group by a.charityid, a.charityname
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67cca and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca00e

```
create table charityTbl (charityid int, charityname varchar(100));
insert into charityTbl values (1, 'Red Cross'), (2, 'Doctors without borders');

create table contributionsTbl (charityid int, totalcontributions int);
insert into contributionsTbl values
(1, 100),
(1, 200),
(2, 500);
```

(Just think that this was a stored procedure and was called with `exec SQL7`)

```
 select a.charityid, a.charityname, sum(b.totalcontributions) as totals
  from CharityTbl a
  left join ContributionsTbl b on a.charityid = b.charityid
  group by a.charityid, a.charityname
```

Result:

```
| charityid |             charityname | totals |
|-----------|-------------------------|--------|
|         2 | Doctors without borders |    500 |
|         1 |               Red Cross |    300 |
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thanks very much for the Help! And to everyone else for supplying an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about [Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
CREATE PROC SQL7
AS
SELECT
    charity.CharityID
    ,charity.CharityName
    SUM(contrib.TotalContrib)
FROM 
    dbo.CharityTbl                  AS charity
    INNER JOIN dbo.ContributionsTbl AS contrib 
    ON contrib.CharityID = charity.CharityID
GROUP BY
    charity.CharityID
    ,charity.CharityName
```

Comment: this doesn't show any code that will add total contributions.

Comment: @isxaker - I'd hope that downvoters would upvote again after corrections are applied. Upvote from me. Thank you for taking time to update your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
create proc SQL7
as
SELECT CharityTbl.CharityID,
    MIN(CharityName) AS CharityName,
    SUM(contribution_amount) AS TotalContribution
FROM CharityTbl
    JOIN ContributionsTbl ON CharityTbl.CharityID = ContributionsTbl.CharityID
GROUP BY CharityTbl.CharityID
```

Where `contribution_amount` is whatever the name of your contribution amount field is.

Comment: why would you `MIN(CharityName)` rather than group on it?

Comment: I am not sure which one has better performance so I choose the one that looks better in my code

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Proc SQL7
As
Begin

Select CharityID, min(CharityName), Sum(Contributions) as TotalContributions
From
dbo.CharityTbl As Ch
Inner Join
dbo.Contributionstbl as Co
on ch.CharityID = Co.CharityID
group by CharityID
End
```

Comment: won't work as you haven't provided grouping on the first 2 columns and square brackets should be `(...)`.

Comment: @ChrisTest - I'd hope that downvoters would upvote again after corrections are applied. Upvote from me. Thank you for taking time to update your answer